# How do I connect Visual Studio 2017 Community with SQL Server 2014 Management Studio via the Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

NET developers, I have installed the Visual Studio 2017 Community and Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express and Management Studio.

I am trying to connect on my database using the option Tools > Connect to Database, selecting Microsoft SQL Server on list. a

Can some one explain to me where the user name and password below come from??
Iam using Windows Authentication, not SQL Authentication.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="cnx" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER1\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=MyNICEDB;
Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=USER;
Password=PASSWORD"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I request for a step by step procedure to make the application connect to the database and be able to login.

Thank You.

Comment: Your help will be very much appreciated

Comment: I guess it depends how you configured that connection - mine reads totally differently

Answer (score 4):

Add `Integrated Security` property to your connection string and set its value to `true`. This will use Windows Authentication instead of SQL Authentication.
It will look like this:

```
     <connectionStrings>
            <add name="cnx" connectionString="DataSource=SERVER1\SQLEXPRESS;
            Initial Catalog=MyNICEDB;
            Persist Security Info=true; 
            Integrated Security = true; 
            User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD";
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Here's an explanation about `Integrated Security` property from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When **false**, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When **true**, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>
> Recognized values are **true**, **false**, **yes**, **no**, and **sspi** (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.
>
> If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.